# Como verificar dois campos ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: javascript

O código a seguir não está retornando `false`. Quando o campo `reg2` estiver vazio e o campo `reg1` estiver selecionado, a função deveria retornar `false`, mas isso não está acontecendo.

Segue o código para análise:
Script que libera a div com o input.

```js
$j("#reg_2").hide();
 $j("#reg1").click(function() {
 if($j("#reg1").is(':checked')){
 $j("#reg_2").show();
 } else {
  $j("#reg_2").hide();
 }
});
```

Parte do HTML

```html
<div  class="wrapper">
<input type = "checkbox" name ="reg1" id ="reg1" />
</div>
<div id="reg_2" class="wrapper">
<span>Nº do registro:</span>
<input id="reg2" name="reg2" type="text" class="input" />
</div>
```

Script que avalia a condição do reg2:

```js
} else if ($j("#reg1").is(':checked') && $j("reg2").val() == "") {
      $j("#reg2").css({
        "border": '1px solid #ff0000'
      });
      alert("É necessário informar o Registro no MAPA").focus();
      $j("#reg2").keypress(function() {
        $j("#reg2").css('style', '');
      });
      return false;
    }
```

`#reg1` é um checkbox e `#reg2` é do tipo input text, se o campo reg2 estiver vazio e o reg1 estiver marcado, a função deve emitir o alerta e retornar falso, mas não está acontecendo.

Comment: Olá Carolina, você esta no Stackoverflow em Português. Poderia traduzir sua pergunta para português?

Comment: O código não está retornando falso. Se o campo reg2 estiver vazio e o reg1 estiver marcado, a função deve emitir o alerta e retornar falso, mas não está acontecendo.

Comment: Você comentou a pergunta por qual motivo?

Comment: Quando o campo reg1 fosse marcado, e o campo reg2 estivesse vazio, deveria executar o alert e retornar falso para a função inicial, mas não ocorreu, o alert é emitido mas não é retornado falso para a função. Isto seria um controle para evitar que campos de um formulário fossem salvos com campos vazios. E não consegui encontrar um erro nesse trecho, pois testei sem essa parte, e funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Parece que tem um `j$("reg2")` que deveria ser `j$("#reg2")`

Comment: Esse erro eu já tinha visto, foi só na hora de alterar o id, o required é solicitado mesmo que o campo reg1 não esteja marcado. Ainda não está retornando false.

Comment: Coloque a parte HTML e poste o resto do seu Javascript

Comment: Não acho que você deva verificar ambos simultâneamente, o que você faz é verificar um, de acordo com o que outro possuir.

Answer (score 1):

Tem que mostrar script completo e tb html para que possamos analisar

Pode colocar antes ou depois do alerta para desmarcar o campo reg1

```
document.getElementById("reg1").checked = false;
```

Comment: O problema é outro não tem nada de errado com a id #reg2 como a autora disse se refere a um campo de texto.

Comment: eu sei, ela postou isso depois, de toda forma ela não manda desmarcar via código

Comment: Se sabe então pode remover a parte irrelevante da resposta. E sobre o checked eu pessoalmente recomendo que mostre aonde exatamente ela deve colocar do código, pois pode perceber que ela ainda é iniciante.

Comment: feito chefe, rs